# CSS in laravel 5.5.3

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have entered my CSS files in the "public" folder, so the "asset" function should work, but I get a 404 error message in all the files.

I am using Laravel 5.5.33.

This is the content of the public folder:

- public

  - css

    - style.css

And this is the call to the CSS file from the blade:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Thank you!

Comment: This looks good to me, are sure the path and file name is correct?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: In another computer it worked perfectly, can it be a problem of the operating system or the environment?

Comment: Are you using `git`? if so then it may be placed in `.gitignore`

Comment: I'm using git, but I have those files locally and the error persists.

Comment: inspect code and show real path to that css please

Comment: Are you using Valet to start your project? What is your root url in the browser?

Comment: Are you using laravel mix with `.version()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you're getting 404 you should check your Laravel's logs first (if there is nothing then check server logs).

But I'm guessing that the problem with this assets is a bad permissions on this directory. Please check if you have read permission for all on this directory.